# Performance Monitor ( perfmon ) - how to open .blg file

Tags: windows, performance, performance-monitoring, perfmon

I have recorded data through perfmon.msc, and save the data. The extension of the Data is .blg.

[image: .blg file]
Whenever i double click the file the below windows get open.
here, i can't see any log which i have recorded
[image]

Please advice how to open this .blg file.

Thanks & Regards,
Param

Answer (score 2):

Try harder Googling, [first entry](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/read-performance-log-file-blg-t3787294.html) when searching for `open .blg`:

> To open the blg file, follow steps below
>
> 1. Click start>>run
> 2. Type perfmon and press enter
> 3. In system monitor cselect and remove the counters currently shown by
>      hitting the delete button
> 4. Click the fourth button that says "View log data" this button has a
>      cylinder icon
> 5. Point and open the blg file.
> 6. To view the log you can click the + sign button which is the 8th button
>      on the top. add the counters and objects that you want to view.
> 7. You can also adjust the graph scale by rihgt clicking inside the graph.
> 8. To highlight a particular counter line, select the bulb icon on the top
>      and click on a counter or a line in teh graph.